# Google Analytics :: Entrance and Exit URL more user friendly in Goal Funnel Report

Tags: google-analytics

This is a more generic question. If you look at the funnel visualization report, we notice the entrances and exits are denoted by Page URLs. Is there any way to configure it such that it is set to Page Title ? What I was hoping to understand is if there any way to make that page URL more user friendly so that it is easy to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change it to anything other the URL. The way we solve it currently is by making the URLs readable.